# unmarshalling into single class using eclipselink

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

i have created a **Company** class that does produce xml like below using marshalling :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns2:company  xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/">
   <ns2:employee>
      <job>sogi</job>
      <name>togi</name>
      <age>22</age>
   </ns2:employee>
</ns2:company>
```

Note:I used @XmlPath("employee/job/text()") tag in **Company** class to get the required path.

but when unmarshalling i use the same **Company** class,i do not get the correct object values.Instead i get null values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include namespace information in the `@XmlPath` annotation.

**package-info**

Since your XML document has namespace qualification, you will need to leverage the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation to specify the namespace information.

```java
@XmlSchema(
    namespace="http://www.example.com/",
    xmlns={
        @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.example.com/", prefix = "foo")
    }
)
package forum14848450;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

**Company**

In the `@XmlPath` mapping for the fragments of the XmlPath that are namespace qualified you need to leverage the prefixes you defined on the `@XmlSchema` annotation.

```java
package forum14848450;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement
public class Company {

    @XmlPath("foo:employee/job/text()")
    private String employeeJob;

    @XmlPath("foo:employee/name/text()")
    private String employeeName;

    @XmlPath("foo:employee/age/text()")
    private int employeeAge;

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html).

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

The demo code below will unmarshal the document from your question, and then marshal it back to XML.

```java
package forum14848450;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Company.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum14848450/input.xml");
        Company company = (Company) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(company, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code.  Note how the output document uses the prefixes defined in the `@XmlPath` annotation.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo:company xmlns:foo="http://www.example.com/">
   <foo:employee>
      <job>sogi</job>
      <name>togi</name>
      <age>22</age>
   </foo:employee>
</foo:company>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html